# Ubuntu on ThinkPad: fan not working and "critical temp reached"

Tags: crash, thinkpad, fan, overheating, temperature

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on ThinkPad L14 Gen 2 (intel). It crashes almost every time compiling a TeX document with more than 20 images. The last few lines of log from `journalctl -b -1 -e` give me:

```
<time-stamp> <my-laptop> thermald[813]: critical temp reached
<time-stamp> <my-laptop> thermald[813]: critical temp reached
<time-stamp> <my-laptop> thermald[813]: critical temp reached
<time-stamp> <my-laptop> thermald[813]: critical temp reached
<time-stamp> <my-laptop> systemd[1678]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
<time-stamp> <my-laptop> thermald[813]: critical temp reached
```

`critical temp reached` explains a bit the situation as I hardly hear the fan working recently. The fan has been working properly before, but now it works only in BIOS phase and stop after entering Ubuntu.

Now I have no idea how to solve either the fan problem or the temperature problem. Can someone help?